# How to establish the connection to SAP Solution Manager using Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, sap-solution-manager

I have a requirement to extract the data SAP solution manager to azure blob using ADF as ETL tool.
I do not find any direct connector to create a linked services on source(SAP SOLUTION MANAGER).

Please advice me how to create linked services to SAP solution manager using ADF. Appreciate your effort.

Regards,
Rajesh K

Comment: what kind of info do you wanna extract from SolMan?

Comment: Microsoft have announced a new upcoming SAP connector that supports CDC today.  See the full announcement here:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/announcing-the-upcoming-preview-of-sap-cdc-in-azure-data-factory/ba-p/3420904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) of supported data stores and formats in Azure Data Factory

> How to create linked services to SAP solution manager using ADF

You can follow this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory#create-a-linked-service-to-an-sap-table-using-ui) to Create a linked service to an SAP table using UI

[image]

Comment: Solution Manager is not a table

Comment: Thanks AbhishekKhandave. Let me try on this. Thanks once again for your input